# Кракозябры в Консольном приложении в C

Tags: c, visual-studio, кодировка

Пишу программу на СИ под VISUAL STUDIO SP1 2010. Сам код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>    

int main(){

    system("chcp 1251 > nul");

    printf("Эта программа! Её написал Я(Влад). Вот так она будет выглядеть!\n");

    system("pause");

}
```

Программа компилируеться и работает без ошибок. НО! Кодировка лагает. Мне выводятся РАЗНЫЕ КРАКОЗЯБРЫ. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это исправить?

Comment: в листинге программы не должно быть кирилицы, английскими буквами введи слова

Comment: это типо хэлоу ворлд?

Comment: почему не должно?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Добавьте

```
#include <locale.h>
```

и после main()

```
  setlocale(LC_ALL,"RUS");
```

Если текст в программе набран в cp-1251 (обычная кодировка в Винде (она же ANSI)) то  русские буквы выводятся **нормально**  как в консоли (cp-866), так и в эмуляторе терминала (в Emacs *eshell*) в cp-1251 (и в файл (переадресация stdout) тоже OK в cp-1251).

Answer (score -2):

Сам лично работаю в CodeBlocks, бесплатная, простая и удобная IDE.Если делаю что-то на Си, то всегда на этой IDE.Никаких проблем с компилятором и кодировками.Раз поставил и всё.

Вот ссылочка на CodeBlocks: [CodeBlocks IDE](http://www.codeblocks.org/downloads/26)

Пробовал и в VS - мне не понравилось, вот C# - другое дело.