# Абракадабра в выводе консоли Cline

Tags: c++, jetbrains

В Cline при попытке вывода кириллических символов появляются абракадабры во встроенной консоли, причем в консоли дебага их нет.
Пробовал это:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
SetConsoleCP(1251);
SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
```

не помогло.
пробовал в Cline изменять кодировку проекта и его файлов на 1251, IBM866, UTF-8: ничего не помогло. Если использовать для вывода консоль Windows, то символы отображаются корректно
Компилятор от VS.
Что может мне помочь?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Кракозябры в Консольном приложении в C](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/67979/%d0%9a%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b7%d1%8f%d0%b1%d1%80%d1%8b-%d0%b2-%d0%9a%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b2-c)

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте поменять фонт я сталкивался с такой проблемой на C# мне помогло просто поменять фонт